# Find a basis for $W=\lbrace a+bx+cx^2+dx^3 \in P_3 | a+3b-2c+d=0 \rbrace$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Recall that $P_3$ is a vector space on under the addition and scalar multiplication.
>
> Let $W=\lbrace a+bx+cx^2+dx^3 \in P_3 | a+3b-2c+d=0 \rbrace$
>
> 1. Prove that $W$ is subspace of $P_3$.
> 2. Find a basis for $W$ (Prove your answer).

This is my attempt, and please if there any mistake tell me because my prof is so careful. Thanks. [sorry I don't speak English well]

1. It is obvious that $\phi \neq W \subseteq P_3$

[To explain why $\phi \neq W\subseteq P_3$,take for example $0=0+0.x+0.x^2+0.x^3$, we have $0+3(0)-2(0)+0=0$. so, $0\in W$, and any element in $W$ will be a polynomial of third degree, so it will be element in $P_3$]

Let $r \in \mathbb{R}$  and $f,g \in W$ such that

$f=a_1+b_1 x+c_1 x^2+d_1 x^3$ and $g=a_2+b_2 x+c_2 x^2+d_2 x^3$

Where $a_i, b_i, c_i, d_i \in \mathbb{R}$, $\forall i\in \lbrace1,2\rbrace$

such that

$a_1 +3b_1 -2c_1 +d_1=0$ and $a_2 +3b_2 -2c_2 +d_2=0$

$rf+g=r(a_1+b_1 x+c_1 x^2+d_1 x^3)+a_2+b_2 x+c_2 x^2+d_2 x^3$

$=ra_1+rb_1 x+rc_1 x^2+rd_1 x^3+a_2+b_2 x+c_2 x^2+d_2 x^3$

$=(ra_1+a_2)+(rb_1+b_2) x+(rc_1+c_2)x^2+(rd_1+d_2)x^3$

Now, we have

$(ra_1+a_2)+3(rb_1+b_2)-2(rc_1+c_2)+(rd_1+d_2)$

$=ra_1+a_2+3rb_1+3b_2-2rc_1-2c_2+rd_1+d_2$

$=r(a_1+3b_1-2c_1+d_2)+(a_2 +3b_2 -2c_2 +d_2)$

$=r(0)+0=0$

Therefore, $rf+g \in W$

$W$ is subspace of $P_3$.

2. Since the dim$\mathbb{R}^2=4$, Then the dimension of any subspace $W$ of $V$ will be less than or equal to $4$, so the dimension of $W$ will be $0, \ 1, \ 2,\ 3$ or $4$.

If $dim(W)=0$ then $W= \lbrace 0=0+0.x+0.x^2+0.x^3 \rbrace$.

This means that $W$ is not contain any non-zero element, but this is not true, since

$0 \neq f(x)=1+x+3x^2+2x^3 \in W$

If $dim(W)=4$ then $W=P_3$, but this is also not true, since $g(x)=1+x+x^2+x^3\in P_3$ but $g(x)\notin W$.

Then $dim(W)$ will be $1,2$ or $3$.

Now, if $p(x)=a+bx+cx^2+dx^3 \in W$ then $a+3b-2c+d=0$

so, $a+bx+cx^2+dx^3=(2c-3b-d)+bx+cx^2+dx^3$

$=c(2+x^2)+b(-3+x)+d(-1+x^3)$

Therefore, $W=span(B)=span\lbrace 2+x^2,-3+x,-1+x^3\rbrace$

now if $\alpha_1(2+x^2)+\alpha_1(-3+x)+\alpha_1(-1+x^3)=0$

we have

$(2\alpha_1-3\alpha_2-\alpha_3)+\alpha_2 x+\alpha_1 x^2+\alpha_3 x^3$

then

$\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\alpha_3=0$

As a result, $B$ is linearly independent.

$B$ is span $W$ and linearly independent, hence $B$ is a basis for $P_3$, and $dim(W)=3$

Comment: Good job. The discussion about the dimension of $W$ not being $0$ or $4$ is useless. Your "pivot" argument is enough to determine the dimension.

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS Thank you so much.